# Running selenium test through physical device

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I work on test automation for a mobile version of a website. I have several tests that I generally run through ChromeDriver or Browserstack. However, what I would really like to do is hook up my phone and run my tests through the phone. I have tried appium but I am starting to realize that it is only used for apps and not mobile versions of websites.. Does anyone have any experience in running tests through a physical device? If so, what tools did you use or do you know of any good online tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

Appium **IS** for testing websites on mobile devices.

You must pass the appium server the `browserName` parameter instead of the `app` parameter.

I suggest reading the [appium documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/).

I have used Appium, Selenium Grid and testNG to run parallel tests for websites on real devices, so if you need any further guidance feel free to ask.

Hope this helps,

Liam.

Comment: Hello, yes I do actually have a lot of questions.. I have downloaded appium, I have set my paths, and I have capabilities set up to run my automated mobile web app tests to run through browserstack.. Can you possibly give me some steps to take to run them through a connected device? I have my device connected and can see it when I run adb devices

Comment: Okay well to run a test on a single device all you need to do is launch the appium server, and run a test script with the correct capabilities for your device! The info for the specifics is all in the documentation.

If you want to do any concurrent testing you will want to use Selenium Grid and TestNG (if you check my profile you will find relevant code in other answers). This requires a hub server and nodes configured to each devices capability, then creating a driver, pass it the hub URL and with the capabilities of a device and the test will run on that device!

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you van use Appium for mobile web application test. In fact you can use native browser or chrome browser in Android. And Safari browser in IOS.

If you want to start the web automation for Android i suggest you to follow the following tutorial with the example code.

[appium-web-application-automation-in-android](https://debugger89.wordpress.com/2015/05/12/troubleshooting-appium-web-application-automation-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this off the top of my head, not while I am doing it. This often leads to it not being 100% correct. There might have to be made some adjustments.

## iPhone

This is what I have done:

1. Download and run Appium Server
2. Install xCode Tools
3. Run iPhone Simulator
4. Get your devices ID, in console, type

   instruments -s devices
5. Set capabilities

   ```
       WebDriverManager.setGlobalExtraCapability("platformName", "iOS");
       WebDriverManager.setGlobalExtraCapability("platformVersion", "14.4");
       WebDriverManager.setGlobalExtraCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 11");
       WebDriverManager.setGlobalExtraCapability("appium:automationName", "xcuitest");
       WebDriverManager.setGlobalExtraCapability("appium:udid", "your devices ID");
       WebDriverManager.setGlobalExtraCapability("browserName", "Safari");
       WebDriver driver = WebDriverManager.getWebDriver();
   ```
6. On the phone you have to set some mode, but I can not find anymore, which one that was. (Please write in comments if you know.)
7. Run Test

I hope I have not forgotten anything, as this was a process.